# Converting NSDictionary to JSON

Tags: json, swift

I have a Core Data entity Checkout that has just one attribute which is transformable and set as [String:Any]:

```
 cart : [String:Any]
```

The function below is used to retrieve the value from Core Data:

```
 func getCheckOutItems()->  [NSDictionary]{
    let request : NSFetchRequest<Checkout> = Checkout.fetchRequest()
    request.propertiesToFetch = ["cart"]
    request.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
    var checkout : [NSDictionary]!
    var cart : [String:Any]!
    do{
        checkout = try context.fetch(request)
    }catch{
        print ("Error fetching data")
    }
    return checkout
}
```

The aim is to add the results of this query to a JSON string that also contains other keys using this function:

```
 var cart = [String:Any]()
    cart["cart"] = getCheckOutItems()
    cart["telco"] = "something"
    cart["fcm_token"] = "tokden"
    cart["email"] = "email"
    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: cart, options: [])
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)
    print("Printing JSON \(jsonString)")
```

This is in order to produce a json result like this:

```
 {
    "fcm_token": "tokden",
    "cart": [{
            "entity": 1,
            "quantity": 1,
            "id": 428,
            "price": 80,
            "date": "30 Jan 2018",
            "seat_no": 20,
            "type": "bus",
            "item": "STANDARD",
            "schedule_id": 132
        },
        {
            "entity": 1,
            "quantity": 1,
            "id": 1539,
            "price": 110,
            "date": "30 Jan 2018",
            "seat_no": 7,
            "type": "bus",
            "item": "EXECUTIVE",
            "schedule_id": 131
        },
        {
            "entity": 1,
            "quantity": 1,
            "id": 282,
            "price": 40,
            "date": "30 Jan 2018",
            "seat_no": 1,
            "type": "bus",
            "item": "STANDARD",
            "schedule_id": 114
        }
    ],
    "telco": "something",
    "email": "email"
}
```

The main issue is that I need to eliminate the key from core data which is highlighted as **"cart": {** in order to get the JSON in the format above. But this has proven very elusive and difficult to achieve!

```
 {
    "fcm_token": "tokden",
    "cart": [{
        **"cart": {**
            "entity": 1,
            "quantity": 1,
            "id": 428,
            "price": 80,
            "date": "30 Jan 2018",
            "seat_no": 20,
            "type": "bus",
            "item": "STANDARD",
            "schedule_id": 132
        }
    }, {
        "cart": {
            "entity": 1,
            "quantity": 1,
            "id": 1539,
            "price": 110,
            "date": "30 Jan 2018",
            "seat_no": 7,
            "type": "bus",
            "item": "EXECUTIVE",
            "schedule_id": 131
        }
    }, {
        "cart": {
            "entity": 1,
            "quantity": 1,
            "id": 282,
            "price": 40,
            "date": "30 Jan 2018",
            "seat_no": 1,
            "type": "bus",
            "item": "STANDARD",
            "schedule_id": 114
        }
    }],
    "telco": "something",
    "email": "email"
}
```

How can I format this result such that the "cart" key is eliminated to format the json as indicated earlier. I am very new to swift and it seems really difficult to wrap my mind around this problem.

Comment: First of all, use Swift 4 Jain parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flatMap`. Try this.

```
let cartItems = getCheckOutItems() as? [[String:Any]]
var cart = [String:Any]()
cart["cart"] = cartItems?.flatMap({ $0.flatMap { $0.value } })
cart["telco"] = "something"
cart["fcm_token"] = "tokden"
cart["email"] = "email"
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: cart, options: [])
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)
print("Printing JSON \(jsonString)")
```